# Filter SharePoint lists by a Person or People Picker

Tags: search, filter, people-picker

How can I create a web part page, where the search web part is a "peoplepicker" like control which then filters 3 SharePoint lists below it on the "CreatedBy" column.

Scenario: Find all entries made by "UserX" in these three SP lists".  "UserX" is not equal to the Current User.  The PeoplePicker search control will only allow the selection of individual users in AD.  UserX may have zero or more entries in each list.

Limitations:  Can only use out of the box web parts, or javascript solutions.

I thought about a "Text field" as the search box, but what if someone misspells the user's name? AD User list is about 3000 employees, so a dropdownlist is out of the question.  A PeoplePicker control would be ideal for this, but not sure how I can implement this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata navigation for this on the default AllItems.aspx and other views. Enable it on List Settings and Choose the Created or Modified field (or a custom Person field if you like). It's an Out of the box feature.